# Microwave steaming - venting/holes optional?

Tags: vegetables, microwave, steaming

I see a lot of cooking videos where vegetables like carrots are steamed in the microwave, and the bowl is covered with what looks like a pretty tight lid without any vents/holes. For instance [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_wQKrqh8Lk). I have always been afraid of doing this because I think that the pressure from the steam created would force the lid out with disastrous consequences. Am I correct? If so, how do the people in these videos not end up with a mess?

Comment: Define disastrous.  Do you fear damaging the microwave or just cleanup?

Comment: Both. In my mind, it would sort of blast open, spraying the hot - whatever is inside, and possibly leave a mess and damage the interior of the appliance (also electric short etc?)

Comment: I think you overestimate the power of the blast.

Comment: ask any emergency doctor what they have seen regarding microwave steam/explosion injuries. Typically to the eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't explode. If you don't have a lid, try it with tightly secured cling wrap. Just don't put a ton of water in there, follow the instructions. It's a nice way to quickly steam veggies. Even if it does explode, the worst that will happen is steam will escape into your microwave and your veggies might dry out. Nothing crazy!

Comment: suggest waiting until 'tent' looks slightly deflated before removing film or other precautions

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ones with the tight lid, and had salmon explode all over the inside of my oven !!